# Can I use 14 AWG pigtails on a 20 amp 12 AWG circuit with 15 amp receptacles?

Tags: electrical, wiring

It seems like this would be OK for the ground pigtail, and probably OK for the hot and neutral too since the receptacle is ony 15 amp capacity. But I wonder if there are safety issues I'm not considering and what the electrical code has to say about it.

Comment: The pigtail would normally be specified by the equipment manufacturer based on the load. If the appliance was only 10 amps for instance then a 14 ga pigtail would be fine and in line with a 20 amp circuit. If you have a 20 amp circuit everything in that circuit should be rated for 20 amps including the receptacle. If you plug a 19 amp load into a 15 amp receptacle for instance, the circuit breaker may not trip and the plug could melt.

Comment: What happens if you plug in two 9amp loads?

Comment: I’d be willing to bet that your wiring device (outlet) is rated at 20amp but has 2 (duplex) NEMA 5-15 faced outlets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You must use a 12 gauge pigtail here

A 14 gauge pigtail on a 20A circuit is a (very short) *tap conductor*:

> **Tap Conductors.** As used in this article, a tap conductor is
>   defined as a conductor, other than a service conductor, that
>   has overcurrent protection ahead of its point of supply that
>   exceeds the value permitted for similar conductors that are
>   protected as described elsewhere in 240.4.

As a result, that 14AWG pigtail violates NEC 210.19(A)(4) Exception 1, which prohibits the use of tap conductors to feed receptacles:

> **(4) Other Loads.** Branch-circuit conductors that supply
>   loads other than those specified in 210.2 and other than
>   cooking appliances as covered in 210.19(A)(3) shall have
>   an ampacity sufficient for the loads served and shall not be
>   smaller than 14 AWG.
>
> *Exception No.1: Tap conductors shall have an ampacity sufficient for 
>   the load served. In addition, they shall have
>   an ampacity of not less than 15 for circuits rated less
>   than 40 amperes and not less than 20 for circuits rated
>   at 40 or 50 amperes and only where these tap conductors
>   supply any of the following loads:*
>
> *(a) lndividual lampholders or luminaires with taps extending not longer than 450 mm (18 in.) beyond any portion of the lampholder or luminaire.*
>
> *(b) A luminaire having tap conductors as provided in
>   410.117.*
>
> *(c) Individual outlets, other than receptacle outlets,
>   with taps not over 450 mm (18 in.) long.*
>
> *(d) Infrared lamp industrial heating appliances.*
>
> *(e) Nonheating leads of deicing and snow-melting
>   cables and mats.*